# How to resolve "User request limit reached" Issue in facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

After I called the Facebook graph API, I am getting this kind of error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#17) User request limit reached","type":"OAuthException","code":17}}
```

Answer (score 10):

You called API too many times (working too hard, huh?). [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/rate-limiting) is how Facebook calculates the Limit. Read the link carefully.

Comment: @bart if you have issues, you can create new question & post related information, especially the API calls you made.

Answer (score 1):

Take extra notice of the part about updates:
"Updates are 10~100 more expensive than creates."

I'm getting this error frequently as I am doing a lot of tests to the Graph API.